# Calculating output_shape when using 3d transpose convolutions in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, deep-learning, convolution

I have a 4D tensor `h0` from a previous layer with shape `[10, 1, 1, 1, 10]` and I want to upsample using `conv3d_transpose` to a tensor `h1` with shape, lets say, `[10, 4, 4, 4, 20]`.

**I do not understand how my choice of `filter`, `strides` and `padding` effect `output_shape`, given `h0`, and hence whether `[10, 4, 4, 4, 20]` is possible for `h1`?** Is there a rule of thumb or formula?

For example, if I run the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()

# Input (previous layer) [batch, depth, height, width, in_channels]
h0 = tf.constant(0.1, shape=[10, 1, 1, 1, 10])

# Filter [depth, height, width, output_channels, in_channels]
w1 = tf.constant(0.1, shape=[5, 5, 5, 20, 10])

# Strides [1, depth, height, width, 1]
strides1 = [1, 4, 4, 4, 1]

# Output shape [batch, depth, height, width, in_channels]
output_shape1 = [10, 4, 4, 4, 20]

# Current layer
h1 = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(value = h0, 
                            filter = w1,    
                            output_shape = output_shape1, 
                            strides = strides1, 
                            padding = 'VALID')

sess.close()
```

I get the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Conv3DBackpropInput: Number of planes of out_backprop doesn't 
match computed: actual = 1, computed = 0
```

But if I change `padding = 'SAME'` then I get no error. I have read about [convolutional arithmetic](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.07285.pdf) but do not understand how the formulas apply to Tensorflow specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Deconv operators are confusing, and I think everybody gets tripped up by them initially. [Here is a convenient set of gifs](https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic) to visualize deconv operations in 2D, which transfers well into 3D. It's easiest to think of as two steps.

1. Upsample the image to some larger size (tensorflow does this by filling with zeros)
2. Do regular convolutions on that upsampled image

With that said, let's look at what's happening in your example.

You have d, w, h = [1, 1, 1] and you want to 'deconvolve' it up to a depth, width, heigh of [4, 4, 4]. You are doing this with a [5, 5, 5] filter that is being moved by strides of [4, 4, 4] in those d, w, h dimensions.

The first step under the hood is to blow up the image to a bigger size (it decides itself how big), in a manner similar to the referenced gifs. That way, we'll be able to do regular convolutions on those blown up images. Then, you take your [5, 5, 5] filter, and apply it in 64 different locations (due to your 4, 4, 4 output_shape). These locations are going to be 4, 4, 4 apart from each other, because that is what you specified the strides to be. In order for these shapes to work out, the initial image needs to get blown up to [17, 17, 17] during the image resizing process. The proof is left as an exercise for the reader (aka, I am too lazy to draw then link an explanation but can do so if you'd like).

The 'same' tag basically says to ignore the nitty gritty details of the input layer and output layer shapes. It pads the border of the input with zeros, so everything has no choice but to work out. If 'same' isn't specified, you need to be rigorous about the shapes, or they won't come out nicely the way you may want them to. To be honest, until you become comfortable with convolutions/deconvolutions, I'd recommend just sticking with the 'same' tag to make your life easier.

On a separate note, your strides/output_shape/filter_size don't really make sense together. Blowing up a [1, 1, 1] image to the necessary [17, 17, 17] will just fill the [17, 17, 17] image with zeros, except for that center point. As such, most of the filters will process all those zeroes, and it'll mess with your output. I'd recommend, instead, doing something like strides=[1, 1, 1], output_shape=[10, 3, 3, 3, 20], w1(aka filter_size)=[3, 3, 3, 20, 10]. That, with the 'same' tag, should give you some reasonable results in that next network layer. This will only move the filter by a stride of 1 for each of the 27 (aka 3x3x3 output_shape spots). This means that each of those 27 will have information going into it, rather than just zeros.

Good luck!

Comment: If I change `output_shape1 = [10, 17, 17, 17, 20]` then I still get an error `InvalidArgumentError: Conv3DBackpropInput: Number of planes of out_backprop doesn't match computed:  actual = 1, computed = 5`. **How did you work out the [17, 17, 17]?** Sorry I do not understand

Comment: I might not have space in a single comment. Right, that's not the output_shape, I should have been more clear. That is the shape that the image will get resized to before having convolutions performed on it. That [17, 17, 17] size is the upsampled image size you need to do convolutions with stride of [4, 4, 4] and a filter of size [5, 5, 5] in order to get an output of [4, 4, 4]. So [17, 17, 17] doesn't need to get coded in anywhere, it gets processed under the hood, specifically if you do the 'same' tag.

Comment: I'll explain how I got [17, 17, 17] in one dimension, but the logic extends to 3. You are applying a filter of size 5 with a stride of 4, and want to get 4 outputs (in the 1D example). The filter starts at position 3, because then its 5 weights don't reach over the edge of the input. We stride it by 4, so the next spot is 7. Then stride by 4 again, you're at 11. Last stride by 4, you're at 15. You still need 2 positions available to the right, because your filter is of size 5, so we need to make sure that it fits in the input.

Comment: _ _ X _ _ _ X _ _ _ X _ _ _X _ _ .      
The first filter is centered at position 3, so its 5 values can fit in the image. The X's mark where the filter will be applied on the resized image. They are spaced apart by 4, as that is your stride. So you need a total of 17 spots in the resized image. This is done under the hood in the conv2d_transpose operation.

Comment: Okay. Suppose `output_shape1=[10, 5, 5, 5, 20]` and `strides1 = [1, 2, 2, 2, 1]` and `w1` and `h0` remain the same with `padding = SAME`. Following your logic in 1D, the filter would go from being centred at 3, to 5, 7, 9, and 11. This would mean `h0` would be resized to 13 along one of its axis and the output of the filter would be 5? When I run this I still get an error in Tensorflow